# Gecko chrome @supports function for strings and numbers

Tags: css, firefox, media, gecko, userchrome.css

in Gecko chrome there is `-moz-bool-pref` it Evaluates to true if the preference is enabled, false otherwise.

for example

```
@media (-moz-bool-pref: "removePopupBorder") {
 ...
}
```

if in the `about:config` i set `removePopupBorder` to `true` the code will run
if i set `removePopupBorder` to `false` the code will not run

now if i have multiple valid values for `removePopupBorder` like `auto` , `then` , `none`
every one of these can run different codes

how can i check what is `removePopupBorder` value

the `-moz-bool-pref` only works with boolean values `true` or `false` but how can i work with strings or numbers

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't, but you can try to use js to get around this and make something custom, or use a basic CSS hack

Comment: can you give examples in an answer